# COM Factory error 0x80040154

Tags: delphi, com, factory

```
CoCreateGuid( fIID );
TComObjectFactory.Create( ComServer, TMyCustomComClass, fIID, aClassName, aClassName, ciInternal, tmApartment );
fResult := CoGetClassObject( fIID, CLSCTX_SERVER, nil, IClassFactory, fFactory );
assert( fFactory <> nil, 'ERROR! fFactory is nil..' ); // fResult ~> 0x80040154 REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
```

TMyCustomComClass inherits from TComObject.

According to MSDN, such error occurs because the CLSID is not in the registry, but by Delphi's TComObjectFactory help, no registry is needed to do this, and the original code did the same and just worked.
I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add in links to the MSDN and Embarcadero help pages you're citing here?  That would help us clear up the confusion.

Comment: [`CoGetClassObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684007.aspx) is a Microsoft COM function, it uses standard COM registrations (hense Registry, unless **Registration-less COM** is used), and thus the CLSID must be known to COM. For this example to work, `TComObjectFactory.Create()` must register the CLSID it is passed. Personally, I think this is a bad example, the `CoGetClassObject()` is redundant when Delphi could simply instantiate `TMyCustomComClass` directly without going through COM.

Comment: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG is pretty clear

Comment: `CoGetClassObject` will succeed once you register the class object, not just create it. [`TComObjectFactory.RegisterClassObject`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComObj_TComObjectFactory_RegisterClassObject.html) looks relevant, or you want other methods of making it available (see Remy's above).

Answer (score 0):

`TComObjectFactory` instance is not visible by Windows COM system until it is registered with `CoRegisterClassObject` API. When you create a new ActiveX library using Delphi - this API is called for each class factory present in library when library is loaded and it's `DllGetClassObject` method is called.

Here is modified version of your code, `TMyCustomComClass` COM object will be visible inside process that created it. This way you can register a new COM object visible in the current process only, without registering it in Windows registry. For example, you can instantiate this COM object using fIID inside WebBrowser control in your process:

```
var
  Factory: IClassFactory;
  Reg: LongInt;
...
  CoCreateGuid( fIID );
  Factory := TComObjectFactory.Create( ComServer, TMyCustomComClass, fIID, aClassName, aClassName, ciInternal, tmApartment );
  CoRegisterClassObject(fIID, Factory, CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, FReg);  // This line registers TComObjectFactory in Windows
  fResult := CoGetClassObject( fIID, CLSCTX_SERVER, nil, IClassFactory, fFactory );
  assert( fFactory <> nil, 'ERROR! fFactory is nil..' );
```